# The case for Jesus Christ

Tags: quran, prophet-isa

The Quran states:

> The Messiah, son of Mary, is no more than a messenger; like whom messengers have passed away; and his mother was trustworthy, they used to eat the food. See how We clarify the signs for them, then see how they deviate. (5:75)

Now, we come to the fact that the Quran here affirms that Jesus (SAW) was the Messiah. But the Jews rejected him, and rightly so in their point of view because he didn't seem to fulfil any of the requirements for the deliverer. So by saying that Jesus (SAW) is the messiah, why does God deny his previous revelation (the Old Testament) itself?

Comment: "rightly so in their point of view". "rightly so"? really? Do you know how many miracles Jesus (AS) brought? They rejected him out of nothing but arrogance. (See Al-Baqara 2:87).

Comment: I don' think you get the question. Jesus ﷺ indeed did not fulfil most of the prophecies and requirements for the messiah.

Comment: The fact that he was a messiah comes after believing he was a prophet. They rejected him as a prophet, which is why they rejected he was a messiah. Not the other way around.

Comment: They rejected him as a prophet despite his signs because of their arrogance.

Comment: What previous revelations did God deny? If as you say Jesus did not fulfill the requirements of the Mashiach, then obviously previous revelations are not denied and yet to come? When you say the Jews rightly rejected Jesus from their point of view, you are very much mistaken as the Jews could not have known at the time of his birth (first denial of Jesus) that he would not fulfill the prophecies in Daniel, Ezekiel, Hosea, Isaiah, Jeremiah, Micah, Zechariah, and Zephaniah. Please refer to [ask], and in specific about doing research beforehand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the prophecies in the Old Testament are not pertienent to Islam and its teachings.

Comment: @III-AK-III Let me clear myself. The Jews had the Torah. The Torah set down laws for them and prophecies for the Messiah, and the requirements too: http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/17-03.html ---- If Jesus didn't fulfil them, why would they accept him? And when the Quran states that Jesus is the messiah, isn't God simply ignoring the conditions he set down in the Old Testament Himself?

Comment: @theliberalmuslim — Thanks for the link, but I still can't understand your question. The Jews denied Jesus on his day of birth. The conditions of building the 3rd temple and gathering all Jews in the land of Israel couldn't have been fulfilled on his day of birth obviously. They weren't justified. The conditions you bring forth are from the Torah that Allah says its words have been changed by the Jews, then you ask why is Allah ignoring such conditions. Your logic here fails me. If you want, we can continue the discussion in [chat].

Answer (score 4):

Your question does not specify exactly which "requirements" of the *Tanakh* Jesus did not fulfill. From your comments, it seems to me that you are unaware of these prophesies, and are also unaware of exactly which scriptural quotes they are based upon. I'd suggest researching them for yourself before proceeding. [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8885/14736) answer on Judaism.SE and [this](http://www.kesser.org/moshiach/rambam.html) might be a start.

Muslims:

- Do **not** believe that the entire Tanakh is un-corrupted. Muslims believe that portions have undergone *Tahrif*: Either the text has been changed or the *Tawil* (interpretation) the People of the Scripture have adopted and propagate is not what was originally conveyed.

  > فبما نقضهم ميثاقهم لعناهم وجعلنا قلوبهم قاسية **يحرفون** الكلم عن مواضعه ونسوا حظا مما ذكروا به ولا تزال تطلع على خائنة منهم إلا قليلا منهم فاعف عنهم واصفح إن الله يحب المحسنين
  >
  > So for their breaking of the covenant We cursed them and made their hearts hard. They distort words from their [proper] usages and have forgotten a portion of that of which they were reminded. And you will still observe deceit among them, except a few of them. But pardon them and overlook [their misdeeds]. Indeed, Allah loves the doers of good.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 5:93](https://quran.com/5/13)</sup>

  > أفتطمعون أن يؤمنوا لكم وقد كان فريق منهم يسمعون كلام الله ثم **يحرفونه** من بعد ما عقلوه وهم يعلمون
  >
  > Do you still fancy that they will believe you, although a group of them used to hear the word of Allah, and then, having understood it, used to distort it knowingly?
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 2:75](https://quran.com/2/75?translations=84)</sup>

  What they claim are "prerequisites" for the Messiah to prove himself to the people are their own conjectures and not based on the scriptures.

- Do **not** believe that all the prophesies apply to Jesus alone (unlike the Christians), nor to a specific and discrete time. The focus in Islam is on the Prophet Muhammad and his *Ummah*, and how they are foretold in the Torah and the Injeel. They spread worship of Allah throughout the earth, took the sword against the unbelievers and oppressors, defeated their enemies, established a caliphate where Allah's law was enforced, restored the Temple (Masjid Al-Haram) and the rituals (sacrifice, prostration and pilgrimage) etc.

  > الذين يتبعون **الرسول النبي الأمي الذي يجدونه مكتوبا عندهم في التوراة** **والإنجيل** يأمرهم بالمعروف وينهاهم عن المنكر ويحل لهم الطيبات ويحرم عليهم الخبائث ويضع عنهم إصرهم والأغلال التي كانت عليهم فالذين آمنوا به وعزروه ونصروه واتبعوا النور الذي أنزل معه أولئك هم المفلحون
  >
  > Those who follow the **Messenger, the unlettered prophet, whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel**, who enjoins upon them what is right and forbids them what is wrong and makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them. So they who have believed in him, honored him, supported him and followed the light which was sent down with him - it is those who will be the successful.
  >
  > <sup>—[Quran 7:157](https://quran.com/7/157)</sup>

  > هو الذي أرسل رسوله بالهدى ودين الحق ليظهره على الدين كله وكفى بالله شهيدا محمد رسول الله والذين معه أشداء على الكفار رحماء بينهم تراهم ركعا سجدا يبتغون فضلا من الله ورضوانا سيماهم في وجوههم من أثر السجود ذلك مثلهم في التوراة ومثلهم في الإنجيل كزرع أخرج شطأه فآزره فاستغلظ فاستوى على سوقه يعجب الزراع ليغيظ بهم الكفار وعد الله الذين آمنوا وعملوا الصالحات منهم مغفرة وأجرا عظيما
  >
  > It is He who sent His Messenger with guidance and the religion of truth to manifest it over all religion. And sufficient is Allah as Witness.
  >
  > Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah ; and those with him are forceful against the disbelievers, merciful among themselves. You see them bowing and prostrating [in prayer], seeking bounty from Allah and [His] pleasure. Their mark is on their faces from the trace of prostration.
  >
  > That is their description in the Torah. And their description in the Gospel is as a plant which produces its offshoots and strengthens them so they grow firm and stand upon their stalks, delighting the sowers - so that Allah may enrage by them the disbelievers. Allah has promised those who believe and do righteous deeds among them forgiveness and a great reward.
  >
  > <sup>—[Quran 48:28-29](https://quran.com/48/28-29)</sup>
- Believe that Jesus's ministry has not been completed yet. He didn't die and was raised up and will return to complete his task, including fulfilling some of the so called unfulfilled prophesies:

  > وإن من أهل الكتاب إلا ليؤمنن به قبل موته ويوم القيامة يكون عليهم شهيدا
  >
  > And there is none from the People of the Scripture but that he will surely believe in him [Jesus] before his death. And on the Day of Resurrection he will be against them a witness.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 4:159](https://quran.com/4/159)</sup>

  > أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ليس بيني وبينه نبي يعني عيسى وإنه نازل فإذا رأيتموه فاعرفوه رجل مربوع إلى الحمرة والبياض بين ممصرتين كأن رأسه يقطر وإن لم يصبه بلل فيقاتل الناس على الإسلام فيدق الصليب ويقتل الخنزير ويضع الجزية ويهلك الله في زمانه الملل كلها إلا الإسلام ويهلك المسيح الدجال فيمكث في الأرض أربعين سنة ثم يتوفى فيصلي عليه المسلمون
  >
  > The Prophet (ﷺ) said:
  >
  > There is no prophet between me and him, that is, Jesus (ﷺ). He will descent (to the earth). When you see him, recognize him: a man of medium height, reddish hair, wearing two light yellow garments, looking as if drops were falling down from his head though it will not be wet.
  >
  > He will fight the people for the cause of Islam. He will break the cross, kill swine, and abolish jizyah. Allah will perish all religions except Islam. He will destroy the Antichrist
  >
  > and will live on the earth for forty years and then he will die. The Muslims will pray over him.
  >
  > <sup>— [Sunan Abu Daud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/34)</sup>

  > قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم والله لينزلن ابن مريم حكما عادلا فليكسرن الصليب وليقتلن الخنزير وليضعن الجزية ولتتركن القلاص فلا يسعى عليها ولتذهبن الشحناء والتباغض والتحاسد وليدعون إلى المال فلا يقبله أحد
  >
  > The Messenger or Allah (ﷺ) said:
  >
  > I swear by Allah that the son of Mary will certainly descend as a just judge and he would definitely break the cross, and kill swine and abolish Jizya and would leave the young she-camel and no one would endeavor to (collect Zakat on it).
  >
  > Spite, mutual hatred and jealousy against one another will certainly disappear and when he summons people to accept wealth, not even one would do so.
  >
  > <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155c)</sup>

Comment: Aren't the hadith you quote portraying forced conversion and terrorism? "Break the cross" is not a particularly pleasant image. I'd like to know the Quranic basis for these claims.

Comment: @theliberalmuslim Your comment is not relevant to the question. The hadith talks about the end of times when truth will be made apparent and the populace will embrace Islam. Jesus will break the cross (to deny that he was killed or preached salvation through crucifixion & resurrection ) and kill the swine (to deny that he abrogated the law). The Quranic basis is the verse 4:159 which I've quoted in my answer before the hadith. To think that he is required to be tolerant and accomodating of false beliefs about himself is absurd.